# PySpark vs SQLalchemy, which is better for dealing with big data?

Tags: python, database, pyspark, bigdata

I have a delta lake with tons of data (200Gb+) and I need to clear it out using something that can run SQL inside Python. I don't want to clear the .parquet files directly, I want to work directly with the database.

My question here is which one should be better for this task?

I thinks it's PySpark due to its distributed computing capabilities, but also it's not uncommon to see people using SQLalchemy to do big queries like this.

(EDIT)

The database have multiple delta tables (\table_name.delta) and some of them have FK. My idea was to use spark directly like:

```
spark.sql(QUERY)
```

But talking with my team I discovered that you cannot delete row directly with pyspark, you have to read the .delta, filter and then overwrite. Also PySpark can't delete in cascade, I didn't know that.

With that in mind I thinks it's better to use **sqlalchemy** for that task.

Comment: SQLalchemy is just an ORM. while pyspark is distributed data processing framework. The parquet files can be read in pyspark and data transformations can be applied in distributed manner on a big cluster.

Comment: yes, but what if I just want to read directly the database? and for now ignore the parquet files

Answer (score 1):

PySpark and SQLAlchemy are not really comparable tools.

SQLAlchemy is just an ORM that can be used to <strike>obfuscate your code</strike> embed database operations in your application. All it is doing is taking input from various method calls and using it to construct a SQL query which is then sent off the database. The database decides the optimal physical access plan that will be used to achieve whatever the query is asking for.

PySpark is a python interface to Spark, which is (among other things) a framework for building data pipelines that will run efficiently on large storage clusters. Unlike SQLAlchemy, Spark itself is going to decide what the query plan will look like and how to orchestrate that across the nodes of the cluster.

Which you should use is probably only a question of what the underlying storage system looks like. Is it a multi-node Hadoop cluster, and your job will benefit from parallel execution across the nodes? Then use Spark. Or, is your storage a single Postgres database? Then use SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe your question isn't structured right. Can you use SQLAlchemy to pull from Delta Lake? Answer is no.

Because the data is already in the delta lake, you pull like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("PullFromDeltaLake") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \
    .getOrCreate()

delta_table_path = "path/to/your/delta/lake"
data_frame = spark.read.format("delta").load(delta_table_path)
data_frame.show()
```

Are you using pandas to manipulate the data after import? Then you can convert to a pandas df like this:

```
pandas_df = data_frame.toPandas()
```

I wouldn't recommend this, because there are a lot of benefits to using spark native tools.

Hope this helps

Comment: calling `load()` like this is not lazy evaluated, so this throws out one of the biggest advantages that Spark provides.

Comment: Also OP is using parquet files, so the underlying storage is probably not mysql...

Comment: Ya, I read delta lake as data lake. updating Answer

Comment: my question wasn't clear enough, I've updated it.